# access modifiers in Java

Tags: java, access-modifiers

---

Edited to fix being marked as duplicate or to be more clear on why it appears to be a duplicate. At the time I did not know that package and default where the same thus reason for this post.

---

now I going through exam questions in preparation for my Java exam and I have a question asking me to explain access modifiers and its asking me about a Package modifier.

I can find info on private, Protected, public and default but can't find anything on Package.

can someone please give me an answer or link me to an article about it?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`package-private` is not a real [modifier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html). You can't type `package-private` and get the system to recognize it as an access modifier. It's really the default, made by not including any other modifiers.

It means that the given members can only be accessed in the same package.

For example, `com.hexafraction.Cow` can access a member with default modifiers(none actually) in `com.hexafraction.Dog`, but `com.foo.Crow` can't access that member as it's not in the same pacakge.

In this example, the following makes up `Cow`:

```
pacakge com.hexafraction;
class Cow{
    void moo(){ //no public, protected, or private modifier
        System.out.println("moo!");
    }
}
```

Edit for the future: In Java 8, `package` will supposedly be the modifier needed for this. Literally typing `default` will still not apply here.

Comment: An example of a package private member would help to clarify your answer.

Comment: @Jeffrey This edit OK?

Comment: An interesting tidbit: as of Java 8, `package` will be a legal access modifier. `default`, on the other hand, will also be a legal modifier, but not for access level.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Link to documentation stating this? And what will not having a modifier do?

Comment: JSR 335: Lambda Expressions. `package` will be an optional modifier, for clarity. I don't know if you have been aware of this, but the official name for package-private access level has so far been "default" access level. The new use of `default` causes confusion, therefore the introduction of `package` modifier, and the rename of the access level to "package-private".

Comment: so its very similar to the default?

Comment: @user2631161 Package-private is the default that is used when no modifier is given.

Comment: Thanks just what I needed to know. Have a good day ^_^

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik The newest [revision of JSR 335](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~dlsmith/jsr335-0.6.2.html) claims `Removed support for an explicit package access modifier. `

Comment: @Jeffrey Interesting, this version has not yet been officially published.

Answer (score 3):

The so-called "package-private" access level is what occurs without a modifier such as `private`, `protected`, or `public`.

Example:

```
public class Test {
    int test;  // package-private
}
```

Anything in the same package, even an unrelated class, can access it, but other classes (even subclasses of the class) outside of the package cannot access it.

[This link to the Java tutorial on the subject](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) should help.